# Visual Studio go to tab by number

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

There is a question about going to a certain tab by number for Visual Studio Code but I couldn't find for Visual Studio. In the browsers usually you can go to a tab by pressing Ctrl + num. Is there similar shortcut in VS or a way to assign it?

Answer (score -1):

Recommend an extension by Justin Clareburt, HotTabs:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JustinClareburtMSFT.HotTabs